# How do I improve the accuracy of a BERT-based multilabel text classification model?

Tags: bert, text-classification

I have a database table with 79,512 rows, each of which describes a category. Each row has a title and a description, and can even have a supercategory. Often, supercategories have categories.

I'm trying to train a model to predict each category's supercategory, to be used in a later model that will categorize other data. However, I never get more than a 20% accuracy on this model. My target is 84% accuracy.

These are multilingual datasets I am working with, so the pretrained model I use is also multi-lingual. However, it is also case-sensitive.

By my count, there are an average 9.86 supercategories per category.

How do I improve the accuracy?

EDIT: I suppose I had better clarify: There is a wide variety of languages here, none of them comprising more than 50% of the whole dataset. Perhaps I should translate the data?

Comment: Do you have a validation dataset? Are you measuring the accuracy on it? Are you evaluating the overfitting? Are you applying early stopping on worsening of the validation accuracy?

Comment: @noe: At this point, both training and validation accuracy are very low.

Comment: One idea I have is to NOT freeze the pretrained model, so that the model gets exposure to my dataset's domain.

Comment: When fine-tuning, don't you use a very low learning rate?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense that the training accuracy is low. Have you checked that your model overfits properly training with a single batch? (this is a typical sanity check for deep learning training)

Comment: @noe, yeah, traning & validation accuracy are both sitting at about 3%

Comment: But have you checked that your model overfits training with a single batch? The idea is that you only use a single batch as your whole training dataset. If everything's correct, you should achieve 100% accuracy. If not, something is wrong with the model, the hyperparameters or the trainig pipeline.

Comment: I heard this neural net debugging advice from Andrej Karpathy [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/karpathy/status/1013244313327681536)